# html5 <audio> doesn't work in smart tv

Tags: html, html5-audio, samsung-smart-tv

I've tried to play local mp3 file using html5  tag, but nothing happens. just silent.
does anybody know how to play sounds on smart tv?
it works only if I put the url for the file from internet, but not with local files

p.s. playing through SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER also does not work.

Comment: I think it would be helpfull if you atleast added your used code to the question. For all we know you are ie. not using file://

Answer (score 1):

[The HTML 5 element is `<audio>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-audio-element), not `<sound>`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because either INFOLINK PLAYER or HTML5 Audio needs an absolute path.
See at this samsungdforum thread for PLAYER solution, i haven't tested using HTML5 Audio yet but this solution is working for PLAYER

http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/df3455b529adf7c4?forumID=dc74e02a51c5f914

see at helpinghand2400 post